# "Invalid value for field 'resource.@': '@'. Resource was not found."

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to work with Google compute engine using Google api client library, Google java resourcemanager library and Google api services library for JAVA.
Now I'm trying to run and then delete instances and sometimes when I polling deletion processes of instances on my request like:

```
 HttpTransport: {
 "kind": "compute#operation",
 "id": "12073243417043395137",
 "name": "operation-1457973162309-52e03d43e2589-0c0c6559-bfd36e97",
 "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a",
 "operationType": "delete",
 "targetLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/instances/a4e7s5123-123",
 "targetId": "11502357121231933",
 "status": "RUNNING",
 "user": "user@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
 "progress": 0,
 "insertTime": "2016-03-14T09:32:42.390-07:00",
 "startTime": "2016-03-14T09:32:42.801-07:00",
 "endTime": "2016-03-14T09:32:47.281-07:00",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/operations/operation-1457973162309-52e04d46e7589-0c0ce559-1234567"
}
```

I receive the responce with strange and confusing error:

```
HttpTransport: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "code": "INVALID_FIELD_VALUE",
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.@': '@'. Resource was not found."
   }
  ]
 },
 "httpErrorStatusCode": 400,
 "httpErrorMessage": "BAD REQUEST",
}
```

I searched and only found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/620393/attempting-to-restart-google-compute-instance-invalid-field-value-invalid-valu) question, which is not very helpful. If someone met with this issue, please, give me some info what it means or how should I handle with it? Thank you.

Comment: This might be useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/620393/attempting-to-restart-google-compute-instance-invalid-field-value-invalid-valu

Comment: Thank you. But as I marked in the original question - I already checked this questio and unfortunatley it's useless.